# How to remove the empty entity from an array

Tags: php

I have a function, which returns back the array. But the way I form this array is by "explode"ing a string. And when I do that, I get an extra empty string.

So now my issue is that I dont want to return the empty array entity.

My function code is shown below:

```
public function purge_file($keys)
{
    if(empty($keys))
        throw new C7_Exception('Missing/Bad arguments');                
    $lib_tools_storage = new C7_Lib_Tools_Storage();
    $file_ids = explode(";",$keys);
    foreach($file_ids as $key)
    {       
        //echo "this is file_id = $key  ";
        if(!empty($key))
            $lib_tools_storage->purge_file($key);       
    }

    return array('result_code' => 0,
                    'data' => array('keys' => $file_ids)
                    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trim the outer semicolons before passing to explode:

```
$keys = '1;2;3;4;';
$file_ids = explode(";", trim($keys, ';'));

print_r($file_ids);

/* output
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)       
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function purge_file($keys)
{
    if(empty($keys))
        throw new C7_Exception('Missing/Bad arguments');                
    $lib_tools_storage = new C7_Lib_Tools_Storage();
    $file_ids = explode(";",$keys);
    foreach($file_ids as $key)
    {       
        //echo "this is file_id = $key  ";
        if(!empty($key))
            $lib_tools_storage->purge_file($key);       
    }

    foreach($file_ids as $key)
    {
        if (!empty($key))
        {
            $keys_new[] = $key;
        }
    }
    return array('result_code' => 0,
                    'data' => array('keys' => $keys_new)
                    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this function `array_filter(explode(",", $params['emails']));`.